# keep dimensions of table when converting to a data.frame

Tags: r

I am using the xlsx package to write tables to an excel file.  I want to use the xlsx package so I can write multiple tabs.  xlsx converts the tables into data.frames and in so doing changes the dimensions.

```
b <- sample( c("bob", "mark", "joanna"), 100, replace=TRUE) 
a <- c( sample( 1:5, 100, replace=TRUE) ) 
a <- data.frame( a , b)

d <- table( a$a , a$b )

e <- data.frame(d)

print (e)
print(d)
```

see how the dimensions of d are different than e.  Is there an easy way to keep the dimensions of d when converting?  I looked around in previous questions and didn't see anyone tackle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for `as.data.frame.matrix`:

```
> as.data.frame.matrix(d)
  bob joanna mark
1   1      7    9
2  10      7    4
3   4      6   14
4   6      8   11
5   5      7    1
```

---

There are different "methods" that are used when calling `data.frame` on different types of inputs. Run `methods("as.data.frame")` to see a list of those. Looking at that list, you would see that there is a specific method for `table`s. You can view that code by just typing `as.data.frame.table`. If you treat your `table` as a `matrix`, you get the behavior I think you're expecting.

Comment: @MatthewR, note that you might want to move the `rownames` to a column in your `data.frame`.